# React infinity loop when making HTTP calls using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, http, infinite-loop

I am trying to make 2 HTTTP calls inside a React component that will then call the setters for 2 properties that are defined using useState. I have followed what I thought was the correct way of doing so in order to prevent inifinite rerendering but this is still happening. Here is my code:

```
function Dashboard({ history = [] }) {
  const [teamInfo, setTeamInfo] = useState(null);
  const [survey, setSurvey] = useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const user = getUser();

  const getSurveyHandler = async () => {
    const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');
    setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);
  };
  const getTeamInfoHandler = async () => {
    const teamInfoResponse = await getTeamInfo(user.teamId);
    setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse);
  };     

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f9fafb';

    getSurveyHandler();
    getTeamInfoHandler();
  }, [survey, teamInfo]);
```

As you can see, I have defined the functions outside of the useEffect and passed in the two state variables into the dependency array that will be checked to prevent infinite rerendering.
Can anyone see why this is still happening?

Thanks

Comment: state variable in dependency array causing the infinite rendering here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `survey` and `teamInfo` in your functions with a dependency on them in your `useEffect`.

`useEffect` runs everytime a dependency changes. You are setting them, causing a rerender. Since they changed, the `useEffect` runs again, setting them again. The cycle continues.

You need to remove those.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f9fafb';

    getSurveyHandler();
    getTeamInfoHandler();
  }, []);
```

The only other thing recommended is to move `async` functions inside the `useEffect` unless you need to call them from other places in the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getSurveyHandler = async () => {
        const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');
        setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);
    };
    const getTeamInfoHandler = async () => {
        const teamInfoResponse = await getTeamInfo(user.teamId);
        setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse);
    };
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f9fafb';

    getSurveyHandler();
    getTeamInfoHandler();
}, []);
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I am new to React (having come from Angular) so all quite new to me!

Comment: No worries, it takes a minute to wrap your head around it. I've dealt with a few infinite loops myself.

Comment: Saying that. I have amended the code as you suggested and I am still getting the issue :(  is there anything else that could be causing it?

Comment: Did you rebuild to make sure it's not running the older code. If you have nothing in your dependency array, it should only run once.

Comment: Do you have an empty array for the dependencies? If you leave it out, then it will run on every render.

Comment: Got it! Putting the empty array back in fixed it. Thankyou !

Comment: Great, that's another thing I had to find out the hard way. No array means trigger every render, empty array means only trigger on the first render.